# How long should i wait before creating an undo command when i'm typing text?

Tags: text-editor, undo, command-pattern

I'm working on my undo chain in my project. I want to avoid that each letter gets undo'd separately, but rather that it undo's chunks of text. So i'm working with a debounce.

Is there a standard waiting time or a best practice to follow? I see that browsers and Word all work approximately the same so i thought there maybe was a standard way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: This may be a better question for [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, will also ask it there.